# Having some confusion with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Some background info;

- LanguageResource is the base class
- LanguageTranslatorResource and LanguageEditorResource inherit from LanguageResource
- LanguageEditorResource defines an IsDirty property
- LanguageResourceCollection is a collection of LanguageResource
- LanguageResourceCollection internally holds LanguageResources in `Dictionary<string, LanguageResource> _dict`
- LanguageResourceCollection.GetEnumerator() returns `_dict.Values.GetEnumerator()`

I have a LanguageResourceCollection _resources that contains only LanguageEditorResource objects and want to use LINQ to enumerate those that are dirty so I have tried the following.  My specific questions are in bold.

1. `_resources.Where(r => (r as LanguageEditorResource).IsDirty)`
    
   neither Where not other LINQ methods are displayed by Intellisense but I code it anyway and am told "LanguageResourceCollection does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method...".
   **Why does the way that LanguageResourceCollection implements IEnumerable preclude it from supporting LINQ?**
2. If I change the query to
   `(_resources as IEnumerable<LanguageEditorResource>).Where(r => r.IsDirty)`
   Intellisense displays the LINQ methods and the solution compiles.  But at runtime I get an ArgumentNullException "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source".
   **Is this a problem in my LINQ code?

   Is it a problem with the general design of the classes?

   How can I dig into what LINQ generates to try and see what the problem is?**

My aim with this question is not to get a solution for the specific problem, as I will have to solve it now using other (non LINQ) means, but rather to try and improve my understanding of LINQ and learn how I can improve the design of my classes to work better with LINQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your collection implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, hence you need:

```
_resources.Cast<LanguageEditorResource>().Where(r => r.IsDirty)
```

Note that `Enumerable.Where` is defined on `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable` - if you have the non-generic type, you need to use `Cast<T>` (or `OfType<T>`) to get the right type. The difference being that `Cast<T>` will throw an exception if it finds something that isn't a `T`, where-as `OfType<T>` simply ignores anything that isn't a `T`. Since you've stated that your collection *only* contains `LanguageEditorResource`, it is reasonable to check that assumption using `Cast<T>`, rather than silently drop data.

Check also that you have "using System.Linq" (and are referencing System.Core (.NET 3.5; else LINQBridge with .NET 2.0) to get the `Where` extension method(s).

Actually, it would be worth having your collection implement `IEnumerable<LanguageResource>` - which you could do quite simply using either the `Cast<T>` method, or an iterator block (`yield return`).

[edit]
To build on Richard Poole's note - you could write your *own* generic container here, presumably with `T : LanguageResource` (and using that `T` in the `Dictionary<string,T>`, and implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>`). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marc G's answer, and if you're able to do so, you might want to consider dropping your custom `LanguageResourceCollection` class in favour of a generic `List<LanguageResource>`. This will solve your current problem and get rid of that nasty .NET 1.1ish custom collection.

Comment: Well, it would still need to get from LanguageResource to LanguageEditorResource, and note the internal use of Dictionary<,> - it isn't *just* a basic collection wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I dig into what LINQ generates to try and see what the problem is?

Linq isn't generating anything here.  You can step through with the debugger.

> to try and improve my understanding of LINQ and learn how I can improve the design of my classes to work better with LINQ.

System.Linq.Enumerable methods rely heavily on the IEnumerable< T > contract.  You need to understand how your class can produce targets that support this contract.  The type that T represents is important!

You could add this method to LanguageResourceCollection:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ParticularResources<T>()
{
  return _dict.Values.OfType<T>();
}
```

and call it by:

```
_resources
  .ParticularResources<LanguageEditorResource>()
  .Where(r => r.IsDirty)
```

This example would make more sense if the collection class didn't implement IEnumerable< T > against that same _dict.Values .  The point is to understand IEnumerable < T > and generic typing.